# How to make mypy satisfied with my MutableMapping[str, int] whose __getitem__ may return None and __setitem__ must not accept None?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, abc

I have the following class which maps a `str` to its corresponding `int` or `None` if there is no such key. I want it to be a subclass of `collections.abc.MutableMapping`. The real logic is a bit more complicated than just `self._record.get()`, but the whole thing boils down to just this:

```py
from typing import Iterator
from collections.abc import MutableMapping


class FooMap(MutableMapping[str, int]):
    
  _record: dict[str, int]
    
  def __init__(self) -> None:
    self._record = {}
    
  def __contains__(self, key: str) -> bool:
    return self[key] is not None
    
  def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> int | None:
    return self._record.get(key)
    
  def __setitem__(self, key: str, value: int) -> None:
    self._record[key] = value
    
  def __delitem__(self, key: str) -> None:
    raise TypeError('Keys cannot be deleted')
    
  def __len__(self) -> int:
    return len(self._record)
    
  def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[str]:
    return iter(self._record)
```

However, `mypy` [complains](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.5.0&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=e23b8a6c51767ee1c774f4e63d16a263) about both the `__contains__()`:

```
main.py:12: error: Argument 1 of "__contains__" is incompatible with supertype "Mapping"; supertype defines the argument type as "object"  [override]
main.py:12: note: This violates the Liskov substitution principle
main.py:12: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#incompatible-overrides
main.py:12: error: Argument 1 of "__contains__" is incompatible with supertype "Container"; supertype defines the argument type as "object"  [override]
```

...and the `__getitem__()` method:

```
main.py:15: error: Return type "int | None" of "__getitem__" incompatible with return type "int" in supertype "Mapping"  [override]
```

I get the latter: The `__getitem__()` method of a `Mapping[str, int]` is supposed to return an `int`, not `None`, but that is not my use case. Changing `int` to `int | None` doesn't help, since `__setitem__()`'s second argument will also need to be changed correspondingly.

The former is even more confusing: The first argument passed to `__contains__()` should be a `str`, since we are talking about a `Mapping[str, int]`. Yet, mypy expected something more generic than `object`, according to [the link it gave me](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#incompatible-overrides). I changed that to `key: object`, [but to no avail](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.5.0&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=32ae34ca04d1de4c34849425d8a9dd0b), as `__getitem__()` wants a `str`.

I know I can just throw `MutableMapping` away or add a comment to explicitly tell mypy that it doesn't need to scrutinize a line, but I also don't want to do that.

How to make mypy happy while retaining my initial use case? I'm fine with using any features supported by mypy 1.4+ and Python 3.11+.

Comment: if you want `__getitem__` to return `int | None` then you can't use `MutableMapping`. `__getitem__` sould return `int`. Why is this the behavior you want? Why not just `return self._record[key]`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This is somewhat similar to [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)'s behaviour of returning 0 for non-existent keys. Due to personal preferences and its current usages (internal), I really don't want to raise a `KeyError` in this case.

Comment: well, that goes against the interface of `MutableMapping`. You can't have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If worse comes to worst I will not inherit from `MutableMapping`, but I'd much prefer a better way if it exists.

Comment: The closest you'll get to what you're looking for is `MutableMapping[str, Any]`. (It's okay to use `Any`. People into static typing often discard the option without considering it, but it's a valid option.)

Comment: note, it isn't like `collections.Counter` since `collections.Counter` is basically a `MutableMapping[T, int]`, and `mapping[key]` always returns `int`, in your case, `mapping[key]` returns an optional type. This is pretty much a core feature of the interface, that `mapping[key]` returns the same type as the second parameter, and `mapping.get` returns `T | None` i.e. `typing.Optional[T]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I said "somewhat". `Counter` doesn't raise a `KeyError` in such a case and neither do I.

Comment: @InSync but *that isn't part of the interface*, that's the critical issue here

Comment: @user2357112 I guess the OP mentioned that they can using `# type: ignore[override]` which I think may be better than `Any`, since then `reveal_type(Foo()['foo'])` is `int | None`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hence this question. I need another mapping-like built-in which accepts this behaviour, but it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @InSync I thought you wanted to use `collections.abc.MutableMapping`? I guess my question is, why do you want to do that, and not just define your own type that isn't derived from `collections.abc.MutableMapping`? Since it seems you are willing to jsut go with *some other type* Is it just for the free implementations of `pop` etc?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's for supporting instance checks: `isinstance(foo_map, collections.abc.MutableMapping) # True`. It is true that I can do so, but, as I said, I prefer a "better" way if it exists.

Comment: @InSync I don't really understand, then. Because you just said you could use  "another mapping-like built-in which accepts this behaviour" but then, you said you merely want to use it so you can do `isinstance`... but you can always use `isinstance`, you could just have `class FooMap: ...` and not inherit from `collections.abc.MutableMapping` snd then use `isinstance(foo_map, FooMap)`.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm not a good communicator. Anyway, from the comments, this seems impossible. I guess I'll have to make do then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually possible to [`.register()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register) a class as a "virtual subclass" of an `ABC`:

```py
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

class FooMap:
  ...

MutableMapping.register(FooMap)
```

This also supports runtime typechecking:

```py
print(isinstance(FooMap(), MutableMapping))  # True
```

Even though I didn't end up using this (too late to change now), it [passes `mypy`](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.5.1&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=fdde4e1f94dd7da3f843435c8b31a805) and fits my purposes nicely.